# Why don't I get the TXT records I was expecting?

Tags: domain-name-system, txt-record, google-domains

I'm using [Google Domains](https://domains.google.com/) to manage DNS of a domain I own. In Google Domains, I've configured a TXT record `_acme-challenge` with a specific value. I was expecting to see this value when doing:

```
dig -t TXT pelicandd.com @ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com
```

but instead I get:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-... <<>> -t TXT pelicandd.com @ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19716
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pelicandd.com.         IN  TXT

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
pelicandd.com.      300 IN  SOA ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 20 21600 3600 259200 300

;; Query time: 16 msec
;; SERVER: 216.239.32.110#53(216.239.32.110)
;; WHEN: Thu Aug 06 22:12:23 CEST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 132
```

Why don't I see the TXT record? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not seeing the `TXT` record because you're not querying the `TXT` record.

Solution: Query the `TXT` record.

```
dig -t TXT _acme-challenge.pelicandd.com +short                                                                             
"a4OJqHKIlQUt689jaZxnfhhNgRDYPtPe9qNxGBczRoU"
```